# Can I delete the open bracket and auto delete the close bracket in the vim?

Tags: vim

Here is the text:

> It is the text outside the bracket. {I am some text in the backet.} This is another text outside the bracket.

I wanna to remove the `{}` inside the text. So, I `f{` and `x` it, and `f}` then `x` it again.... is there any easy method for me the delete the bracket? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just find all the brackets and replace them with empty string? (Sorry, but it's not very clear what you're trying to achieve here.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### put your cursor to block

<kbd>f</kbd><kbd>{</kbd>

#### yank inner block

<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>{</kbd>

#### select entire block

<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>{</kbd>

#### overwrite selected block

<kbd>p</kbd>

---

**Note:** It works on multi-line block.

Comment: Very nice. Takes care of nesting, multiline, etc. If the poster does this a lot, just map it to a key.

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another way, and like kev's answer, it works on multi-line blocks and respects nesting braces.

Move your cursor to the block:

<kbd>f</kbd><kbd>{</kbd>

Jump to other end:

<kbd>%</kbd>

Delete brace at the end:

<kbd>x</kbd>

Jump back to where you started (these are backticks):

<kbd>`</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>

Delete brace at the beginning:

<kbd>x</kbd>

Here it is altogether:

<kbd>f</kbd><kbd>{</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>`</kbd><kbd>`</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on "easy", but

```
:s/{\([^}]*\)}/\1/
```

Use with modifiers in regular order to handle multiple replacements per line, etc.

On a single bracket pair, this is more work than your manual example, but if it concerns many replacements it saves time.

EDIT: the difference between this and searching for all brackets and removing them (`:s/[{}]//`) is that this only removes balanced brackets, but with some quirks (nesting, as I mentioned).

"What am I *really* trying to do?" is almost always worth explaining in a question to get better answers.